# SQL max With Ties

Tags: sql, max, partitioning

```
TABLE1
STUDENT SCORE   CLASS
1   1   A
1   1   A
1   9   B
2   5   A
2   10  A
3   6   A
3   4   A
3   9   B
3   8   C
3   8   C
```

I HAVE TABLE1 above and want to take the MAX(SCORE) for all STUDENT-CLASS COMBINATION, but I only wish for ONE Row when there is duplicates, to get this OUTPUT:

```
STUDENT CLASS   SCORE
1   A   1
1   B   9
2   A   10
3   A   6
3   B   9
3   C   8
```

My attempts give DUPLICATES when there is a TIE

> ```
> SELECT STUDENT, CLASS, MAX(SCORE) OVER PARITION BY (STUDENT, CLASS) AS WANT
> FROM TABLE1
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a window aggregate here, just use `group by`

```
SELECT STUDENT, CLASS, MAX(SCORE) SCORE
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY STUDENT, CLASS
ORDER BY STUDENT, CLASS;
```

See [Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AC7MnXsM)

Comment: but this still give duplicates. Also when to use window aggregate vs not?

Comment: This won't give any duplicates for the sample data you have shown - have you tried it? See [demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AC7MnXsM)

Comment: I see it works thank you sooooo much. WHen to use the group by vs window aggregate?